# java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name ResBundle, locale en_GB

Tags: java

I am receiving following exception while I have created a `ResBundle` class in same package which extends `ListResourceBundle` class.

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name ResBundle, locale en_GB
```

**My calling code**

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ResBundle", locale);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("ResBundle")
```

tells the classloader to load a resource named "ResBundle" with default package (that is, no package).  It does NOT mean a resource in the current package that has the referencing class.

So try giving the package path and see if the issue gets resolved.